# Flutter firebase_storage : [firebase_storage/unknown] An unknown error occurred

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

i want to upload voice recorder to firebase storage and when i upload i got this error
**[firebase_storage/unknown] An unknown error occurred** i am using this package to record
voice audioplayers **https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers**
i will upload the photo to my code (code upload the voice to firebaseStorage).
[image: code upload recorder here]